# Uniform distribution, generating function, characteristic function and

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, uniform-distribution, characteristic-functions

Let $$P(X = k) = \frac{4}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$$ for $k ≥ 1$. I need to show that the generating function $φ_X(u) = E(u^X)$
satisfies $φ_X(1)=1,φ′_X(1_−)=2<∞$ , but $ φ′′ (1_−)=∞$.

By the way, in this case$|φ′ (u)|≤2$ uniformly in $|u|<1$ while still $φ_X(u) = ∞$ for all $|u| > 1$. If something is unclear, I am more than happy to add information and I am thankful for your help.

Comment: This is showing some strange non-ASCII characters (two of them before the first $k$ in the denominator, one at the beginning of the line after the display).  Please use only ordinary ASCII.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the generating function?

Comment: What does this have to do with uniform distributions, by the way? Anyway, It looks like you can compute $E(u^X)$ with some basic manipulations on geometric series. Have you tried this already?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for you comments, I will edit it tomorrow when I am back home. Excuse the wrong notation, I will also edit in my approach. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

We compute the generating function:

\begin{align}
\varphi_X(s) &= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{4 s^k}{k (k+1) (k+2)}\\
 &= \frac{3 s^2-2 s^2 \log (1-s)-2 s+4 s \log (1-s)-2 \log (1-s)}{s^2}.
\end{align}
From here we have
$$
\lim_{s\uparrow1}\varphi_X(s) = 1
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf d s}\varphi_X(s) = \frac{-2 (s-2) s-4 (s-1) \log (1-s)}{s^3}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{s\uparrow1}\varphi_X'(s) = 2,
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathsf d^2}{\mathsf d^2s}\varphi_X(s) = \frac{2 ((s-6) s+(4 s-6) \log (1-s))}{s^4}
$$
so 
$$
\lim_{s\uparrow1}\varphi_x''(s) = \infty.
$$
We can verify this as $1-\lim_{s\uparrow1}\varphi_X(s) = \mathbb P(X=\infty)=0$,
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 4{(k+1)(k+2)} = 2,
$$
and
$$
\mathbb E[X^2] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {4k}{(k+1)(k+2)} = +\infty.
$$